# Run XSL tranformation on an Mei file(xml) Using Saxon

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am trying to do what I considered to be a simple thing but I do not seem to understand how to go withit.

I have an mei file which is essentially an xml  and I want to apply an xsl Transformation on it.

I am using saxon for that and this is what I have been doing.

```
  Processor processor = new Processor(false);
  XsltCompiler xsltCompiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
  XsltExecutable exec = xsltCompiler.loadExecutablePackage(myURI);//URI containing my own xsl file
  net.sf.saxon.s9api.Xslt30Transformer transformer = exec.load30();
```

Problem is that I get an exception in this line             `XsltExecutable exec = xsltCompiler.loadExecutablePackage(myURI);`
saying `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Loading compiled packages requires Saxon-PE or higher (even when no license is needed)`

Question Does anybody now if there is an alternative path that I can take which does not involve the need to deal with the PE license ?

If not I canot even understand how I should go with it meaning I am using saxon in a gradle project which means that even for the downloaded saxon-PE jar I installed it in my local m2 repository and reference through gradle so how can I even let the jar now about the licence.

FYI: This is a project that runs in an amazon Lambda enviroment.

Comment: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation.html should also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `loadExecutablePackage` is for loading a precompiled stylesheet. You just want to compile a stylesheet from source XSLT - for that, use the `compile` method.

You might find it useful to look at the sample applications included in the saxon-resources download file, available as a separate download from [www.saxonica.com](http://www.saxonica.com).

Comment: Thank you that was really helpfull !